# Display angularjs-dropdown-multiselect inline along with drop down label name

Tags: angularjs, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect .

code sample:

```
PLatform : <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" extra-settings="example13settings"></div>
```

JS:

```
     $scope.example13model = []; 
    $scope.example13data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, 
{id: 2, label: "Jhon"},
 {id: 3, label: "Lisa"}, 
{id: 4, label: "Nicole"}, 
{id: 5, label: "Danny"} ]; 
    $scope.example13settings = { smartButtonMaxItems: 3, smartButtonTextConverter: function(itemText, originalItem) {
 if (itemText === 'Jhon') { return 'Jhonny!'; } 
return itemText; } };
```

reference : http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main

I want to display label name and dropdown in a single line as below.
[image]

But after using multi select api i am unable to display then inline, it displays as below, please let me know how to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that putting it in a span instead of a div solves the problem.

Try this instead:

```
Platform
<span
  ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
  options="example13data"
  selected-model="example13model"
  extra-settings="example13settings">
</span>
```